# Making blank datetimepicker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'd like to make blank datetimepicker in vb.net. how to? User doesn't like to see any date if it's not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just set the DataTimePicker to visable = false?